# Patents and papers out of my field of research

Tags: research-process, independent-researcher, changing-fields, patents

I am a Ph.D. candidate and my field of research is digital signal processing. But, from a lot of years I have two ideas:

1. A new technique useful in the biomedical field.
2. A paper or, better, an improvement of an unit of measure in physic.

This two things are completely off topic in my field of research.

**The question is: there are ways for publishing, patenting in other topics?**

Thank you in advance,
Giacomo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each case, you need to verify that your ideas are novel and useful in the context of their own fields, and express them in the languages of those fields. It may be better, rather than going independent, to explain the situation to your advisor, and ask for recommendations and introductions to researchers in the relevant areas.

I have some experience of the patent process, fortunately as an employee with my employer paying all the costs. It has its own language. Converting an idea to a properly constructed series of claims is a specialized skill. I have had trouble reviewing a patent application to check that it correctly reflected an invention I completely understood. I have no idea how much it costs to get a patent written up and filed, but it is definitely not free.

If the original work were done "on the job" as a supported researcher, you need to check into the university's intellectual property rules and your own contracts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that the route for a patent in not easy, but in this moment my curiosity is if I can go out of my field of research. I live in Italy, and our laws recommended to produce material in my topic. But... it is a lot of time that I have these two ideas and now I have found you. :-)